# Div border seems to have a 'pointed' edge

Tags: css, border

I noticed that there seems to be a 'sharp' edge of a div border. I have this declaration:

```
.stat-table .stat-box.box-default{
   border-top: 5px solid black;
}
```

[image]

What can be the possible workaround for this? Thanks

Comment: Could you also please show the markup? Are you able to get this angled border effect to happen in a JSFiddle?

Comment: (offtopic) @JHS please don't suggest jsFiddle is it's doable within a code-snippet (available in Editor tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is occurring (without seing the code) is because the element has borders on all sides, of different thicknesses.

The borders always join each other on an angle, [example in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0udgk7k/).

To be able to have the top border be angle-less we will have to cheat a bit, simulating a top border with a div. First, lets create the parent element:

```
.the-element-that-needs-a-border {
    position: relative; 
    /* (or absolute or fixed depending 
    on the needs of your layout) */
}
```

In this parent element we create an empty div and style it:

```
.fake-border {
    /* making it absolute lets us position it freely 
    inside its relative (of fixed or absolute) parent */
    position: absolute; 

    /* this is technically the "width" of the border */
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;

    /* positioning 0px from top */
    top: 0;

    /* this one is a little tricky, we have to position 
    these values to the negative width of the parents 
    border, so assuming the border of .the-element-that-needs-a-border
    is 3px we set this accordingly */
    left: -3px;
    right: -3px;
}
```

Once again, [heres a fiddle to play around with!](https://jsfiddle.net/qf2sh5g5/) :)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great one! Thanks. I also thought about the angled concept right after I encountered the problem, but this answer really got the solution. Thanks! +1

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

`border-radius: 1px;`

i.e.

```
.stat-table .stat-box.box-default{
   border-top: 5px solid black;
   border-radius: 1px;
}
```

or you can set `border-radius` to whatever amount you like. If you want it to almost be circle-like, do `border-radius: 50%`

check out this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Answer (score 0):

If u want to have different angled border at different corners use this. It will be assigned in the following order top-left, top-right, bottom-right and bottom-left.

`.stat-table .stat-box.box-default{
   border-top: 5px solid black;
   border-radius: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
}`

check it here https://jsfiddle.net/Altair827/cffxs7g0/

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a box-shadow that is a solid color and only offset on the Y-axis. Tough to saw without markup, but it looks like that could be it. Inspect the CSS of the element and see if it has box-shadow.